# Failed to load symantec vip javascript

Tags: single-sign-on, symantec

I'm receiving this output while accessing Single Sign On through IE

"Failed to load symantec vip javascript!"

I also see Symantec Vulnerability Protection addon is always disabled, also after enabling it